# AMDGPU problems installing elementary OS 6 beta 2

Tags: grub, graphics, amd, release-odin

I am on elementary OS 5.1.7 and trying to install elementary OS 6 beta 2. I used Etcher to create my live USB. However, when booting up from the live USB, I am only getting a blank screen.I am on AMD A8-7680 Radeon R7. This is what running lspci inside the eOS beta gives me:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev e2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Radeon R7 Graphics
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Memory at feb00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

I tried putting nomodeset to the grub config before booting up, and it does start. However, the graphics is big and low quality. It also shows this error before showing the display:

```
*ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
```

I searched for this error and tried setting these boot options:

```
amdgpu.dc=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 radeon.cik_support=0 radeon.si_support=0
```

But it does nothing. The screen just shows my motherboard's splash screen (not the eOS splash screen).

Answer (score 0):

Also had big issues using hybrid graphics mode on a HP Zbook with Intel Integrated graphics as well as and AMD Radeon Pro WX 3200 graphics card.

blank screen when booting up live iso as well as after installing Elementary OS 6 Odin.
Has to use nomodeset as you to get it working.

Tried going to AMD to get the latest graphics drivers but they do not support the kernel version that Elementary is shipped with (5.11.x).
Downgraded to kernel 5.4.0 and all issues I was experiencing has gone away.